# How to record voice with background track when headphone is plugged

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-audio

I am developing app like karaoke recording . I am able to record entire audio stream including background track  when head phone  not plugged into device . But when headphone  plugged into device, it is recording only vocal stream  not including  background track . i want to record vocal stream including background track.

My code is :

```
//For Recording

  NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
 [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
 [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

 NSError *error = nil;

 audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                          initWithURL:soundFileURL
                          settings:recordSetting error:&error];
 audioRecorder.delegate=self;

 AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                        error:&error];

[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                                 error:&error];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                                     sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
[audioRecorder record];

//  Playing  Karaoke video file 


NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[CommonUISetting applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",songInfo.fileName]]] ;

movieController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewPlayer.frame.size.width, viewPlayer.frame.size.height)];
[ movieController play];
[movieController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[viewPlayer addSubview:movieController.view];
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Answer .... @hotpaw2 thanks for hint  ..

In theamazingaudioengine we can add the instance as a receiver of more than one source, and these will be mixed together automatically.

Thanks to 
The Amazing Audio Engine

Here is solution :

http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/_receiving-_audio.html#Recording

Answer (score 2):

To record mic input plus a music track, the app has to play that track using one of the APIs that allows raw audio sample capture (Audio Queues, or a tap on AVAudioEngine, etc.), then mix that captured data with the recorded input from the selected microphone before saving the mix to a file.